# How to Apply CSS-Style Backdrop Filter and mix-blend-mode in Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, canvas, graphics

I'm working on a Node.js project using the 'canvas' package, and I want to replicate the CSS-style 'backdrop-filter: blur(20px);' and mix-blend-mode: luminosity; effect on a canvas element. Can anyone provide guidance on how to achieve this?
I need to create a canvas with a background image and apply a backdrop filter and mix-blend effect on a rectangle over it.
I tried using `ctx.filter = 'blur(20px)';`, but it's not what I am looking for, it completely blurs the rectangle instead I want the background to be a blur
Any help would be appreciated!

P.S. In the duplicate answer they only show the example with backdrop blur, but I wanted to have the `mix-blend-mode: luminosity;` effect too. I have more questions to ask related to back-drop and the blend mode, like I also want to have rounded corners on the rectangle.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas'); // access the canvas object
const background = document.getElementById("source");
background.onload = function() {
  
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d'); // access the canvas context
    const canvasWidth = background.width; // Set your desired width
    const canvasHeight = background.height; // Set your desired height
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, background.width, background.height);
    const rectWidth = canvas.width / 2;
    const rectHeight = canvas.height / 2;

    // Draw the rectangle
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)'; // White with 80% opacity
     
    ctx.fillRect(
      canvas.width / 2 - rectWidth / 2,
      canvas.height / 2 - rectHeight / 2,
      rectWidth,
      rectHeight
    );

  
}
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<div style="display:none;">
  <img id="source" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534644107580-3a4dbd494a95?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2070&q=80" width="500" height="500" />
 
  <img id="overlay" src="" width="300" height="300" />
  
</div>
```